# What does M.N.L. mean at the end of a personal letter in the 1850s?

Tags: american-english, abbreviations

What does M.N.L. stand for at the end of an 1854 letter, as in "(the letter writer's name)" followed by a vertical squiggly line, then "Yours &C.&C. M.N.L." which was then followed by what I would call a P.S. note: "I will write you again when we set out which will be in six or eight weeks M.N.L." MNL is not the letter writer's initials.

Comment: Can you post a photo if you don't get an answer soon? Is this a USA letter?

Comment: CAn you add some information such as country of origin of writer, was it personal or business etc?

Comment: @Clare The idiom is definitely American, where it says "I will write you..." A British correspondent of the period, as today, would not drop the preposition "to" - as in "write to you". The "&C" was a form of "etcetera".

Comment: @WS2 really? I never knew that 'I will write you' was not in the mid 19th century not a BrE constitution. Is it also not one today? And are you saying &C was/is also not used by a British correspondent?

Comment: @Clare No the *&C* was also used in Britain, but it is now quite obsolete.  "Write" in Britain has to take a preposition in front of an indirect object. It is like "speak", not like "send". The matter has been extensively discussed on this site in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the rest of the letter's contents, M.N.L. could mean *My New Love*.  That possible meaning is listed in various lists of acronyms.

Comment: Can you link to one or more of these lists of acronyms where you found this? Also can you confirm these lists collect acronyms *relevant to the time* and place asked about in this question? If the letter said "afk" it wouldn't be helpful to answer "various lists suggest that stands for *away from keyboard*", because that doesn't apply to the stated context.

Comment: Some of the lists I found that meaning for M.N.L. are 
https://www.acronymfinder.com/MNL.html and
https://www.acronymattic.com/MNL.html 
These lists did not specify either a time or a place where the abbreviation was in use.  I mentioned it as a possibility if the rest of the letter's contents supported such an interpretation.  I do not know if the letter's contents support this possibility.
The author may have used acronyms for ideas he has mentioned.  In that case, the meaning may be found by reading previous letters.  This suggestion is pure speculation.